# установлено display : block , а элемент не отображается

Tags: javascript

> Когда я нажимаю на cancel button,скрываю div Edit и после показываю div Info.
>   Срабатывает первое условие :

```js
function main() {
  var info = document.getElementById("Info");
  var edit = document.getElementById("Edit");
  var edit_button = document.getElementById("Edit_button");
 
  if (getComputedStyle(info).display == "none" && getComputedStyle(edit).display == "block") {
    edit.style.display = "none";
    info.style.display = "block";
    edit_button.style.display = "block";
    alert("INFO" + info.style.display + " Edit" + edit.style.display + "Edit_Button" + edit_button.style.display);
  }
  if (getComputedStyle(edit).display == "none" && getComputedStyle(info).display == "block") {
    info.style.display = "none";
    edit_button.style.display = "none";
    edit.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#Info {
  display: block;
}

#Edit {
  display: none;
}

#Edit_button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Info">
  ....
</div>

<input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit_button" onclick="main()">

<div id="Edit">
  <form name="Edit_form" method="POST" onsubmit="">
    ...
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="main()" class="Button">
</div>
```

Тот alert выводит - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО! edit div остается(должен спрятаться),а info div не появляется.

Comment: Ну ничего себе какие технологии...Вот это отредактировали!Спасибо!

Comment: После первого условия совершенно очевидно срабатывает второе условие, в котором показывается edit и прячется info

Comment: @andreymal Как оно может срабатывать,если я не нажимаю на edit_button,что бы оно выполнилось?Я ничего не понял,простите)

Comment: А какая разница, что вы нажимаете, если у вас при нажатии на любую кнопку вызывается один и тот же `main()`? Естественно, оба условия проверяются на обоих кнопках по порядку сверху вниз. В первом условии вы делаете `edit.style.display = "none"` и `info.style.display = "block"`, после чего дальше внизу по коду проверяется второе условие — и согласно предыдущим изменениям оно оказывается истинно срабатывает. В вашем коде нет ничего между первым и вторым условием, что помешало бы второму условию сработать

Comment: @andreymal вот это да..Я и не подумал про это)Все,добавил return для каждого условия.